# How to remove the lag in the livesearch box created using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code for HTML

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="get">
   <div class="form-group">
        <select id="basic2" onchange="location=this.value;" class="show-tick form-control" multiple>
               <optgroup label="Popular Cities">
                    <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;">Select City</option>
                    <option>UP</option>
                    <option>Anchorage</option>
                    <option>Phoenix</option>
               <option>Little Rock</option>     
           </optgroup>
       </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery
 I want to add a timeout function here to delay the search. how and where to add that function please help!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            var mySelect = $('#first-disabled2');
    
            $('#special').on('click', function() {
                mySelect.find('option:selected').prop('disabled', true);
                mySelect.selectpicker('refresh');
            });
    
            $('#special2').on('click', function() {
                mySelect.find('option:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
                mySelect.selectpicker('refresh');
            });
    
            $('#basic2').selectpicker({
                liveSearch: true,
                maxOptions: 1
            });
});
```